# console.log doesn't show React state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a project which needs to encapsulate the letter has been typed by the user

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [usedLetter,setUsedLetter] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown',handleKeydown);
    }
  },[])

  function handleKeydown(event){
    const letter = event.key;
    setUsedLetter(usedLetter => [...usedLetter,letter])
    console.log(usedLetter);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Used letter : {usedLetter}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This block of code produced a strange behavior. When I monitor state from react developer tool, everything was normal. The result show on the browser was normal. But when it came to the console, specifically `console.log(usedLetter);` the value stored in `usedLetter` was nothing even after I had hit a number of character. I have tried to access `usedLetter` through `useEffect` and it worked but it was inconvenient because I had to break the flow and accessed it outside of event listener callback

Can anyone tell me why this happen and how can I work around to get the real `usedLetter` (the one show on the browser) inside the event listener callback ?

Thanks a million

Comment: State is guaranteed to be stable throughout a render cycle (barring mutation) so the updated state value won't be available until the next cycle (and thus your console.log reflects the un-updated state). Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Yes, I expected `console.log` to be 1 step behind of the actual value that `usedLetter` hold. But reality is that all the time `usedLetter` referenced by the `console` held nothing. I think it is more related to closure like your link propose.

Comment: Yes, I didn't read you snippet closely enough. This is definitely a closure issue caused by the listener only being added on first mount. (The handler is declared on each render so doesn't suffer this problem, but the listener has formed a closure over it as declared on first mount). The cleanest solution is just to add `usedLetter` to the dependency array of the useEffect. `useEffect(() => {...}, [usedLetter]);`

Comment: Tks dude, it worked like i expected :)

Answer (score 0):

useState only sets the new state which it does asynchronously in nature.
there is an npm package called react-usestateref

Check out this codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-bardeen-1gyo3?file=/src/App.js

I used the accepted answer from here to figure it out:
[React hooks: accessing up-to-date state from within a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847594/react-hooks-accessing-up-to-date-state-from-within-a-callback)

Comment: Tks dude, work like a charm, but is this library widely used ? I am just a noob in reactJS, I think using a third party library too soon may spoil my react learning process :(.

Comment: That's a fair statement. I adapted the accepted answer from that SO to fit your need. Checkout this code sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-murdock-fo01f?file=/src/App.js

I added in some comments to the code that I used to make it work.