# How to get the latest state value in event handlers in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this sample. Let's say we have this structure and we want to check some state value in the `onChange` handler of an input. In this case I've used the input value to do the `if` check, and if the condition doesn't pass, we set up an error. However, when I type in 10 characters, the input doesn't trigger the if block right away, but on the next typing. I know that state changes are asynchronous, which is why we'd mostly use `useEffect`, but in this case, I cannot use it for an event handler.

So I am wondering what is the best way to handle this type of situations, when you need to check some state value inside an event handler and perform some actions based on that.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function onChange(event) {
    if (value.length < 10) {
      setValue(event.target.value);
    } else {
      setError(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      {error && <h2>Error triggered</h2>}
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks: accessing up-to-date state from within a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847594/react-hooks-accessing-up-to-date-state-from-within-a-callback)

Comment: But also here it seems you should use `event.target.value` rather than `value` to check length, otherwise you'll be stuck once you enter 10 characters as `value` will never update again after that (even if you delete characters)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem.

```js
function onChange(event) {
    if (event.target.value.length >= 10) {
      setError(true);
    } else {
      setError(false);
    }
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're checking the length of the state value instead of the current value that the input field holds.

When the user types in the 10th character, the state variable `value` still holds 9 characters, and so the `if` check passes even though the length of what `event.target.value` returns is 10.

Change your function so:

```
function onChange(event) {
  const currentValue = event.target.value
  if (currentValue.length < 10) {
    setValue(currentValue);
  } else {
    setError(true);
  }
}
```

This also solves the problem (mentioned by @Henry Woody) of not updating the state even when the user deletes characters that exceed the limit.