# How do I tell another component that the setState of useState changes are done so when they get the value it will be the updated value from an event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Similar to:

- [How to use `setState` callback on react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247433/how-to-use-setstate-callback-on-react-hooks) but I am trying to do this with functional component specifically and I am not trying to replicate the exact same scenario.
- [React hooks: accessing up-to-date state from within a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847594/react-hooks-accessing-up-to-date-state-from-within-a-callback) but I am not passing the state from the callback

So say I have a `notify()` method that I want to be fired AFTER the states have changed, not during state change.  Also after I `click`.

something like

```
const handleClick = useCallback(()=>{
  const [state,setState] = useState("bar");
  ...
  setState("foo", ()=> {
  ... at this point `state` should be "foo" ...;
  notify("yo we're set. but I am not passing the current state to you");
  })
});
...
```

a component that is **child** of the context

```
const { state } = useSomeContext();
subscribe(()=>{
  console.log("I want ", state, " to be the updated value, but I get the existing value); 
});
```

- [`useStateRef`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-usestateref) lets the callback know but the ones listening when they query the value that is in the state may not get the updated value.
- [`useStateCallback`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61725731/242042) does not solve the problem for me either because it's the callback that has the value.

---

The workaround I sort of ended up with (still testing it) is to utilize a `useRef` to the value somewhat like [`useStateRef`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-usestateref) and do `stateRef.current` instead of just `state`

Comment: The answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/56247433/3001761 do use function-based components, hooks don't work in class-based components

Comment: `useEffect` as mentioned in the answer linked by both of you is indeed the way to go here. You mentioned "another component", but it's unclear whether that would be a parent, sibling, or child. Depending on the case, the react team has been discouraging `useEffect` lately, and recommending calling callbacks from the same action that calls the `useEffect` instead

Answer (score 0):

When you change the state via the setter, it will cause the current component to re-render. If the component you want to 'notify' is within the current component and has a dependency on the state value that changed e.g.:

```
return (
  <>
    <SomeOtherComponent something={state}/>
  </>
)
```

... then that component will re-render as well.

If the component you want to notify isn't in the render path, you can make the state a dependency of a `useEffect` so your useEffect will run whenever the state change (and do your notification there). You can have multiple useEffects with with dependencies on different state. Example:

```
useEffect(()=> {
  console.log('hello, state is',state)
}, [state])
```

And you can look into context and other mechanisms to communicate state. You should [read this article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively). I think it's very inline with what you'd like to do.

Certainly don't do anything in your `useState` setter other than the minimal needed to return the new state.