# State array not updating properly in React Native with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, socketmobile

I am working on the react native sdk for socket mobile and for some reason I am unable to reliably set state with `useState` in my react native application. The state change happens in a callback that I pass to Socket Mobile's capture library. Sample app can be found here (for some reason hyperlinks aren't working).

https://github.com/SocketMobile/singleentry-rn/blob/main/App.js

The callback, `onCaptureEvent`, listens for various capture event types. Based on these event types, we manage the state accordingly. One way we do that is when there is a `DeviceArrival` event (when a scanner connects to our iPad/Android Tablet), we then open the device so we can see it's properties, change those properties, etc.

We also try to update a list of devices that come in. So if a device "arrives", we add it to a list and then update the state like so.

```
 setDevices(prevDevices => {
                prevDevices = prevDevices || [];
                prevDevices.push({
                  guid,
                  name,
                  handle: newDevice.clientOrDeviceHandle,
                  device: newDevice,
                });
                return [...prevDevices];
              });
```

This works for the first time, but then it doesn't work properly and the remove device function we have is unable to find the right device to remove (because either an old device is left behind or there is no devices in the list at all).

I have also tried doing it this way...

```
setDeviceList((prevDevices) => [...prevDevices, newDevice]);
```

This way we're not mutating the state value directly. However, when I do it this way, it doesn't work at all. When I try to find the device in the device list to remove it, it shows an error saying it cannot be found.

How or why am I unable to consistently update the list? I've looked at a number of tuts and it seems like the second way should work. I am assuming it has something to do with the fact that it is a callback function but we're not sure of a way around it other than this way.

We have also tried using `useCallback` for `onCaptureEvent` as well as making it asynchronous so we can use `await` in the function. Some state items do update accordingly (we have a state value `status` in the example) but maybe since it's a string it's easier to detect/persist the state change?

Below is the portion of the `onCaptureEvent` function that we think is the culprit.

```
const onCaptureEvent = useCallback(
    (e, handle) => {
      if (!e) {
        return;
      }
      myLogger.log(`onCaptureEvent from ${handle}: `, e);
      switch (e.id) {
        case CaptureEventIds.DeviceArrival:
          const newDevice = new CaptureRn();
          const {guid, name} = e.value;
          newDevice
            .openDevice(guid, capture)
            .then(result => {
              myLogger.log('opening a device returns: ', result);
              setStatus(`result of opening ${e.value.name} : ${result}`);
              setDevices(prevDevices => {
                prevDevices = prevDevices || [];
                prevDevices.push({
                  guid,
                  name,
                  handle: newDevice.clientOrDeviceHandle,
                  device: newDevice,
                });
                return [...prevDevices];
              });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              myLogger.log(err);
              setStatus(`error opening a device: ${err}`);
            });
          break;

    ...

}
```

I am using  `"react": "17.0.2"` and `"react-native": "0.68.2"`

**UPDATE 07/11/23**

I discovered that when I `console.log` the `devices` just before the `return` statement of the component's UI, the device list is reflected correctly. I tested this with a `useEffect` that gets triggered whenever `devices` gets updated. See below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('USE EFFECT: ', devices);
  }, [devices]);
```

This ALSO logs the updated device list. It seems the only place where I am unable to keep track of the updated list is in the `onCaptureEvent` function. I'm guessing this is because onCaptureEvent is a callback that is not directly invoked by the RN component. Any ideas around this? I've used helper functions within the component outside of the `onCaptureEvent` method but it still doesn't seem to work--or at least `onCaptureEvent` is unable to find the updated state value.

Is there a way to ensure

Comment: It's best to provide a [mre] so that potential answerers can be shown the issue directly.

Comment: @Unmitigated I figured it was easier to just leave in the pertinent parts of the code and then leave a link to the sample app rather than include everything

Comment: The key part here is **minimal**, but still reproducible (as described in the help center page above).

Comment: The minimal example is pretty much the sample. I could remove some parts of it but it would still be pretty hefty.

Comment: Does anything else set that state in any way? If so would be good to include that.

Comment: @Abe the only other place I'm setting state in that moment is `setStatus`. I tried removing it but it didn't help. I did notice that if I add the device, then click save in my IDE, the device list is correct. Not sure if that provides anymore insights.

Comment: Did you provide `devices` and `setDevices` in the dependency array of the useCallback?

Comment: @Abe thanks for your input! I think I found a solution. I added it as an answer.

Comment: @Unmitigated thanks for your input! I think I found a solution. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out was wrong.

I am planning on writing a blog post about it to be more in depth but basically the state WAS updating correctly and within the context of the `App` component was up to date and accessible.

The problem I think lies in that fact `onCaptureEvent` is NOT called or referenced directly by anything in the `App` component. Rather, it is invoked as a callback, almost as a side effect, of a third party library (in this case the CaptureSDK).

Since it is passed to the CaptureSDK and invoked because of events that occur in the SDK, more complex data structures (Arrays and Objects) are harder to persist consistently.

`status` was accurately reflected because it was a string. As were other state values that were integers, booleans, etc. These are much easier data types to detect differences in.

An array or object, however, is a bit more difficult for functional components to immediately detect/register. For instance, if you updated an array, set the state using the new array, then immediately tried to log `myArray`, you might not see the reflected values.

So not only were we trying to access state in a callback that has a different invocation context but we are also SETTING the state within this different context. I think this combination allowed for the appearance of state not being updated or accessible.

**The Solution**

To remedy this, I found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847594/react-hooks-accessing-up-to-date-state-from-within-a-callback) where the accepted answer made use of the `useRef` hook. For example, I could use `useState` to initialize and later in the code set the value for `devices`. I could also (after initializing with `useState`) create a reference instance called `stateRef` where I can store the `devices` reference.

```
const App = () =>{
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([])
  const stateRef = useRef();

  stateRef.current = devices

               ...

}
```

Then in `onCaptureEvent` I can set the state as usual, but when I want to reference the latest `devices`, I can use `stateRef.current`. I can use this list to find the `removeDevice`, remove it from the list and then set the state-and properly determine which device was removed.

```
case CaptureEventIds.DeviceRemoval:
   let devs = [...stateRef.current];
   let index = devs.findIndex((d) => {
        return d.guid === e.value.guid;
   });

   if (index < 0) {
      myLogger.error(`no matching devices found for ${e.value.name}`);
       return;
   }

   let removeDevice = devs[index];
   devs = devs.splice(index, 1);
   setDevices(devs);
   break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try this code?

```
 setDevices((device ?? []).concat({
                  guid,
                  name,
                  handle: newDevice.clientOrDeviceHandle,
                  device: newDevice,
                }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The list still doesn't seem to update correctly.  I did notice however that if I add the device, then click save in my IDE, the device list is correct. Not sure if that provides anymore insights

Comment: Thanks for your input! I think I found a solution. I added it as an answer.