# React set useState doesn't work when the selected feature in openlayer changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers

I'm building this react app using open layer but I have a problem with a setState.

I'll explain how the 2 involved components work:

MapWrapper: a component that wraps the open layer map. Inside of this there is a listener that checks everytime the mouse cursor moves and send to the parent component (OlMap.js) the feature found in that screen pixel or null if there isn't any feature there.

This is the listener:

```
initialMap.on('pointermove', function (e) {
  let newSelectedFeature = null

  initialMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (f) {
    newSelectedFeature = f;
    console.log("HOVER", newSelectedFeature)
    return true;
  });
  
  props.onHoverFeature(newSelectedFeature)
});
```

This is the complete component:

```
// react
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

// openlayers
import Map from 'ol/Map'
import View from 'ol/View'
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector'
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector'
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ'
import {transform} from 'ol/proj'
import {toStringXY} from 'ol/coordinate';
import OSM, {ATTRIBUTION} from 'ol/source/OSM.js';

//css
import "./MapStyle.css"
import { Feature } from 'ol';
import { Point } from 'ol/geom';
import Style from 'ol/style/Style';
import Icon from 'ol/style/Icon';

function MapWrapper(props) {

  // set intial state
  const [ map, setMap ] = useState()
  const [ featuresLayer, setFeaturesLayer ] = useState()
  const [ selectedCoord , setSelectedCoord ] = useState()

  const [ selectedFeature, setSelectedFeature ] = useState(null)

  // pull refs
  const mapElement = useRef()
  
  // create state ref that can be accessed in OpenLayers onclick callback function
  //  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643670
  const mapRef = useRef()
  mapRef.current = map

  const highlightStyle = new Style({
    image: new Icon({
      src: "https://i.imgur.com/gbfpoiQ.png",
      //src: "file:\\\\assets\\icons\\badMarker.png",
      anchor: [0.5, 1]
    })
  })

  const markerStandardStyle = new Style({
    image: new Icon({
      src: "https://i.imgur.com/GJ8XUQ7.png",
      //src: "file:\\\\assets\\icons\\badMarker.png",
      anchor: [0.5, 1]
    })
  })

  const changeSelectedFeature = (f) => {
    setSelectedFeature(f)
  }

  // initialize map on first render - logic formerly put into componentDidMount
  useEffect( () => {

    // create and add vector source layer
    const initalFeaturesLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource(),
      style: markerStandardStyle
    })

    // create map
    const initialMap = new Map({
      target: mapElement.current,
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),
        }),
        initalFeaturesLayer        
      ],
      view: new View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: [1877145.5647310177, 5030935.7155071795],
        zoom: 14
      }),
      controls: []
    })

    // set map onclick handler
    initialMap.on('click', handleMapClick)

    initialMap.on('pointermove', function (e) {
      let newSelectedFeature = null
    
      initialMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (f) {
        newSelectedFeature = f;
        console.log("HOVER", newSelectedFeature)
        return true;
      });
      
      props.onHoverFeature(newSelectedFeature)
    });

    // save map and vector layer references to state
    setMap(initialMap)
    setFeaturesLayer(initalFeaturesLayer)

  },[])

  // update map if features prop changes - logic formerly put into componentDidUpdate
  useEffect( () => {

    if (props.features.length) { // may be null on first render

      // set features to map
      featuresLayer.setSource(
        new VectorSource({
          features: props.features // make sure features is an array
        })
      )

      // // fit map to feature extent (with 100px of padding)
      // map.getView().fit(featuresLayer.getSource().getExtent(), {
      //   padding: [100,100,100,100]
      // })

    }

  },[props.features])

  // map click handler
  const handleMapClick = (event) => {

    // get clicked coordinate using mapRef to access current React state inside OpenLayers callback
    //  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643670
    const clickedCoord = mapRef.current.getCoordinateFromPixel(event.pixel);

    console.log(clickedCoord)
    props.onClickMap(clickedCoord)

    // transform coord to EPSG 4326 standard Lat Long
    const transormedCoord = transform(clickedCoord, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')

    // set React state
    setSelectedCoord( transormedCoord )

    console.log(transormedCoord)
    
  }

  // render component
  return (      
    <div ref={mapElement} className="map-container"></div>
  ) 

}

export default MapWrapper
```

OlMap: this is the parent component. It receives in the function onHoverFeature the feature found; then if it is different from the previous feature found, it should set it in the state but setSelectedFeature is called but doesn't work

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import MapWrapper from './MapWrapper'
import MapSearchBar from './MapSearchBar'
import SideSlider from './components/SideSlider'

import { Feature } from 'ol';
import { Point } from 'ol/geom';
import Style from 'ol/style/Style';
import Icon from 'ol/style/Icon';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';

export default function OlMap(props) {

    const [showRightSlider, setShowRightSlider] = useState(true)
    const [coordsToShow, setCoordsToShow] = useState([0,0])
    const [features, setFeatures] = useState([])
    const [selectedFeature, setSelectedFeature] = useState(null)

    const highlightStyle = new Style({
        image: new Icon({
          src: "https://i.imgur.com/gbfpoiQ.png",
          //src: "file:\\\\assets\\icons\\badMarker.png",
          anchor: [0.5, 1]
        })
      })

    const onClickMap = (coord) => {
        setShowRightSlider(true);
        setCoordsToShow(coord)
        createMarker("TEST", coord)
    }

    const onHoverFeature = (f) => {
        if(f?.ol_uid === selectedFeature?.ol_uid) {
            return
        }
        if(selectedFeature) {
            selectedFeature.setStyle(undefined)
        }
        if(f){
            f.setStyle(highlightStyle)
        }
        setSelectedFeature(f)
    }

    let idFeature = 0

    //create marker
    const createMarker = (name, coord) => {
        console.log(name, coord)

          const marker =  new Feature({
             geometry:  new Point(coord),
             name: name,
             id: idFeature++
          })

        setFeatures(oldFeature =>  [...oldFeature, marker])
    }

    return(
        <div style={{height: "90%", width: "100%", backgroundColor: "yellow", position: "relative"}}>
            <SideSlider show={showRightSlider} coord={coordsToShow} onClose={() => {setShowRightSlider(false)}}></SideSlider>
            <MapSearchBar></MapSearchBar>
            <MapWrapper features={features} onClickMap={onClickMap} onHoverFeature={onHoverFeature} /*selectedFeature={selectedFeature}*/ />
        </div>
    )
}
```